# C - Unexpected output with #define

Tags: c, output

When i compile the following program I get the output as 47. I expected the output to be 144

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define FIRST_PART 7
#define LAST_PART 5
#define ALL_PARTS FIRST_PART + LAST_PART
int main() {
printf ("The Square of all parts is %d", ALL_PARTS * ALL_PARTS) ;
return(0);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try minimize you example, and make the title more precise: unexpected how?

Comment: Use your compiler settings to output the preprocessed file. You will find that your expectations are wrong, as this is correctly calculated as `7 + 5*7 + 5`, which indeed is `47`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preprocessor works before the compiler. It is a simple 'stupid' text-replace mechanism. Therefore:

- `ALL_PARTS` gets converted to `7 + 5`
- `ALL_PARTS * ALL_PARTS` gets converted to `7 + 5 * 7 + 5`.

Because of this mechanism, it is recommended to surround the parameters of macros with parentheses and also surround the whole macro with parentheses, such as:

`#define ALL_PARTS (FIRST_PART + LAST_PART)`

Answer (score 1):

`FIRST_PART + LAST_PART` will evaluate as 7 + 5 (It's no more than a text substitution).

You expression is then 7 + 5 * 7 + 5 which is 7 + 35 + 5 (as multiplication has a higher *precedence* than addition). The value of 7 + 35 + 5 is, of course, 47.

A remedy is to use `(FIRST_PART + LAST_PART)` as your definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALL_PARTS * ALL_PARTS
```

Will become

```
FIRST_PART + LAST_PART * FIRST_PART + LAST_PART
```

Which is

```
7 + 5 * 7 + 5 = 7 + 35 + 5 = 47
```

So 47 **is** the expected answer.

If you want to see **your** expected result, you need to add `()` to your `define`

```
#define ALL_PARTS (FIRST_PART + LAST_PART)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Preprocessor evaluated  as

```
printf ("The Square of all parts is %d", ALL_PARTS * ALL_PARTS) ;
```

then

```
printf ("The Square of all parts is %d", FIRST_PART + LAST_PART * FIRST_PART + LAST_PART) ;
```

and then

```
printf ("The Square of all parts is %d", 7 + 5 * 7 + 5) ;
```

So your final result is `47`

To get desired result you can use

```
#define ALL_PARTS (FIRST_PART + LAST_PART)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to change this:

```
#define ALL_PARTS FIRST_PART + LAST_PART
```

To this:

```
#define ALL_PARTS (FIRST_PART + LAST_PAR)
```

Answer (score 0):

FIRST_PART is 7
LAST_PART is 5

FIRST_PART + LAST_PART is 7 + 5

7 + 5 * 7 + 5 = 7 + 35 + 5 = 47

To fix, do

```
#define ALL_PARTS ( FIRST_PART + LAST_PART )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is expanded to 7+5*7+5 = 7+35+5 = 47.
This is a very common failure.